# Trying to set data array to $scope after calling function from view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set data array to $scope after calling function getDetails(detail) from view, but when i do that i can't see my data in my view but if i console.log it in my controller the data is there.

view where i click sending data to controller:

```
 <hr>
  <ul class="rel-results">
 <li ng-repeat="detail in details">
  <a ng-click="getDetails(detail)" href="#/details"> {{detail.longName} </a>
 </li>
  </ul>
```

view that is redirected and i want the information:

```
  <div class="testt">
    <ul class="test">
      <li ng-repeat="routedetail in routedetails">
       <a ng-bind="routedetail.name">{{routedetail.name}}</a>           
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

my routes:

```
 angular.module('myApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/routes", {
    templateUrl: "routes.html",
    controller : "transportController"


});

$routeProvider.when("/details", {
    templateUrl: "details.html",
    controller : "transportController"

});

$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/routes"});
});
```

controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('transportController', function($scope, $http, $base64){

$scope.getDetails = function(detail){
var encoded = $base64.encode("xxx:xxx");
$http({
  url: "xxx",
  headers : {
    "X-AppGlu-Environment":"staging",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+encoded,
    "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  method: 'POST',
  data: { 
    "params":{
      "routeId": detail.id
    }
  }
}).then(function(response){ 
    $scope.routedetails = response.data.rows; 
    console.log($scope.routedetails); // it's possible to see the data here it's a array of objects
   console.log($scope.$id); // i can't see this id in my view
 });

 }
});
```

Comment: So what does structure of `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.routedetails));` look like?

Comment: A array of objects but it's the same as console.log(routedetails);

Comment: I'm not sure but i think it's something like this scope i'm trying to add  $scope.routedetails = response.data.rows;  it's not the scope of the controller

Comment: what is the output of `console.log($scope.$id);`?

Comment: A array of objects Gracia

Comment: Please include the value of `response` and your whole `$scope` in your question

Comment: @LouieAlmeda asking for the whole scope output is pointless and generates needless noise. That userps asking for relevant information like the data structure of the part OP is trying to repeat over

Comment: I made it anyway @LouieAlmeda it's in the question

Comment: Is the html even inside the scope of the transportController? Really simple to output the whole array in view by doing `<pre>{{routedetails|json}}</pre>`. If you see nothing then there is a scope problem in view and need to see more html further up or see how controller is being set

Comment: @charlietfl i made what you said, the result was nothing, it's almost everthing of the controller there, i add the routes maybe it's something with it

Comment: is there an `ng-controller` in that view somewhere? The routes must be right since the controller is firing and logging data although seems strange you have same controller for 2 routes

Comment: @charlietfl no there is not ;(

Comment: no idea what to suggest...are you sure you are loading the correct template?

Comment: yes it is ;(  so sad

Comment: maybe is that <a ng-click="getDetails(detail)" href="#/details" >{{detail.longName}}  i call the function that gives me the routedetails and then change the template but in routesConfig i use the same controller, i don't know if have any problem with that

Comment: that definitely sounds like issue. When  you change view, same controller is used but it is a new instance . I'm guessing you only see this data logged in console right when you click and change view? If you want the data to show you need to call that function in the controller when controller fires

Comment: @charlietfl yes is like you said i see data in console after changing template i'm going to put more information to the question

Comment: I added information about the templates is better for understanding now

Answer (score 0):

I made two jsfiddle with working examples: [Example JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/andrebonna/gcm8ce2q/)

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('transportController', function($scope, $http, $base64) {

    //Initialize array outside : IMPORTANT
    $scope.routedetails = [];

    $scope.getDetails = function(detail) {
        var encoded = $base64.encode("xxx:xxx");
        $http({
            url: "xxx",
            headers: {
                "X-AppGlu-Environment": "staging",
                "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded,
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                "params": {
                    "routeId": detail.id
                }
            }
        }).then(function(response) {

            //Clear entire array
            $scope.routedetails.splice(0, $scope.routedetails.length);

            //Fill array with returned data
            response.data.rows.forEach(function(element) {
                $scope.routedetails.push(element);
            });

        });
    }
});
```

[Example JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/andrebonna/jh1LLvth/)

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('transportController', function($scope, $http, $base64) {
    //Initialize array outside : IMPORTANT
    $scope.routedetails = [];

    $scope.getDetails = function(detail) {
        var encoded = $base64.encode("xxx:xxx");
        $http({
            url: "xxx",
            headers: {
                "X-AppGlu-Environment": "staging",
                "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded,
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                "params": {
                    "routeId": detail.id
                }
            }
        }).then(function(response) {

            $scope.routedetails = response.data.rows;

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried both but no changes the ng-repeat keeps without data

Comment: Please post an example of the content of console.log($scope.routedetails);

Comment: This format :       [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]      from console.log($scope.routedetails)

Comment: Example of object : 0: Object
id: 47
name: "TICEN"
route_id: 22
sequence: 1
__proto__: Object

Comment: `$scope.$apply` is flat out wrong to use in `$http` since it is already done internally and will cause `digest in progress` error.